# im looking for a way to get data from movie db

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have written this function to  get json file from movie db  but it returns an error.

```
function Moviedb($movieID)
{
    $url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/$movieID?api_key=<api*****key>";
    $jsonContent = file_get_contents($url);
    $arrContent = json_decode($jsonContent, true);
    return $arrContent;
}
```

**Error:**

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/tt7286456?api_key=): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

even I use curl for my request but it returned nothing.

and i have checked url in my browser 
it returned data when i did that

any help would be appreciated

Comment: <api*****key> replace thissection with actual key

Comment: you tried curl? then enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and show the verbose log

Comment: yes i tried. but returned nothing.and i enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE .nothing changed.and url is correct because when i used in browser i got data